# QGis - QgsComposerScaleBar - nearest km

Tags: qgis

I added a QgsComposerScaleBar to a QgsComposition.

I wish to have segment rounded to the nearest km but I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

After browsing the documentation a little more, here is how I'd do it :

```py
# Create the scale bar and position it
x, y = 217, 192
w, h = 35, 18
scalebar = QgsComposerScaleBar(composition)
scalebar.setItemPosition(x, y, w, h)
scalebar.setStyle('Single Box')
scalebar.setComposerMap(map)
scalebar.setFrame(False)

# The default map unit is "meters", but you wanted the scalebar in "km"
# The map has to have an appropriate coordinate system, though.
# WGS84 won't work, for instance, as it uses angular units.
scalebar.setNumMapUnitsPerScaleBarUnit(1000)
scalebar.setUnitLabeling("km")

# Find out the total size of the scalebar, in map units (m)
scalebar_size = map.extent().width() / map.rect().width() * w

# Convert it to km
scalebar_size /= 1000.

# Find the size of a segment
number_of_segments = 2
segment_size = scalebar_size / number_of_segments

# Round it to the nearest km, with a minimum of 1 km
# Note that for smaller maps this will create a huge scalebar!
segment_size = max(1, round(segment_size))

# Divide the scalebar
scalebar.setNumSegmentsLeft(0)
scalebar.setNumSegments(number_of_segments)
scalebar.setNumUnitsPerSegment(segment_size)

# Finally, add the scalebar to the composition
composition.addItem(scalebar)
```